# Conversion of annual interest rate compounded monthly to monthly effective interest rate

Tags: interest-rates

I am given that the annual interest rate is $r=4\%$ and that it is compounded monthly. I have to find the monthly effective interest rate.

If I wanted the annual effective interest rate, I would use the formula $r_e=(1+\frac{.04}{12})^{12}-1=.0407$ to find the yearly effective interest rate.

Then to go from yearly effective interest rate to monthly effective interest rate I would use: $r_e=(1+.0407)^\frac{1}{12}-1=.0033$.

Is this method correct? $.33\%$ does not seem high enough. Is there a more direct conversion?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am voting to close this question for being too basic as per https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. This topic is covered in the early chapters of most introductory textbooks such as Hull's "Options, Futures and Other Derivatives" or Sundaresan's "Fixed Income Markets and Their Derivatives".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your result and your reasoning is correct. Just notice that there is a shorter way to the answer: $4/12 = 0.33$.
Indeed, if the annual monthly compounded interest rate is $4\%$ than this means you get $4/12\%$ of interest every month!